# onRestoreInstanceState is never called / savedInstanceState is always null

Tags: android

I have looked in all the site and I don't understand why it's not working on my side.

Please find my source code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.e("EVERYTHING", "OK");
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("test", "titi");
    Log.e("Save", "titi");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I launch my appli, then press the home button, then restart my phone and launch the appli again, but the savedInstanceState is null.

Could you please help me.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

`onSaveInstanceState` is used to persist state in memory so it's not suitable for situations like you described above. If you restart your phone, obviously all state store not persistently (only in memory) is not preserved.

If you want to store state this way, you should look at something persistent, e.g. shared preferences or SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Without using SQLite, is it possible to used the shared preferences in order to save ArrayList?

Could I used a Serializable implementation to save the class in a file, then read it and load it when the appli is launched?

Comment: Yes, you could use shared preferences with some effort. You could serialize to a file as well. It's really up to you.